# Disabling Windows 11-styled menus from Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, windows-11

I am using Chrome v104 and Windows 11 Enterprise.

The new rounded-corners menus in Chrome are really annoying. They collapse some of the items in the right-click menu and that is really inconvenient for me, as I am a web developer and make use of the "Inspect" option a lot. In the new menu, the last visible option is "View page source" which results in the source page being opened, obviously.

I understand that this behavior used to be able to be disabled via the use of a flag(**#win11-style-menus**), but said flag has now disappeared and it seems I'm stuck with the new menus, at least on my Windows 11 machine.

What do I do? I just wish Microsoft would stop with this new-model-year nonsense and stick to the tried-and-tested stuff - or at least not force others to use their design.

Comment: I just wish Microsoft would stop with this new-model-year nonsense ..... This is a Chrome issue, not a Windows issue - at least not on my Windows 11 machines.

Comment: Try this [registry edit](https://www.pcgamer.com/windows-11-context-menu-fix-right-click/).

Comment: @harrymc Done it already. It only works for File Explorer. Also on my machine, it does not affect all the menus.